# How can I use grep to get a substring in Linux?

Tags: linux, grep

I have a string such as follows:

> {"projects":{"1633045839405":
>   {"name":"goal2","created":"2012-11-10T19:10:06Z","modified":"2012-11-10T19:10:06Z","customMetadata":{}},"1976708868731":{"name":"goal1","created":"2012-11-11T11:35:12Z","modified":"2012-11-11T11:35:12Z","customMetadata":{}}}}

I want to use grep to get the substring 1633045839405.

How can i do this with grep?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some reason to not use a JSON parser? Python could do this very easily.

Comment: You probably want to use `cut`, not `grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is structured (like in your case, it is json), you'll only make your life harder with regex. Use a scripting language that has a parser for it, for example python or ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use AWK or Perl instead of grep for this sort of operation.

For example, in AWK you could do something like this:

```
awk -F\" '/ *regular expression here* / {print $4}'
```

Comment: And what would be the regular expression?

Comment: A regular expression, in short, it's the pattern you want to search for.  The simplest regular expression is simply the string you want to search for.   A good write up on the web is available on wikipedia: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)